# android: how to handle force close

Tags: android

In my application when the memory is low, the force close popup occurs. What I want is to handle that force close pop up in my application. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot control this popup from your own application. This is controlled by the Android OS. It is better to analyze what is causing your FCs.

If your error is caused by memory issues, you could try implementing the onLowMemory-function in your Activity. This is a callback function that will be called once the system detects it needs more memory.

Comment: as @piyushnp answers shows, this is not true. Also if you are developing an application that is a little bit more complex than few screens and four buttons it may be hard to find all the possible bugs before you release. Getting logs and user feedback when unexpected happens can be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can completely **control/handle ForceClose Dialog** ! so it doesn't show up to user.

Use [ACRA - Application Crash Report for Android](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) to collect Crash generated by app. Once you integrate it with your app, if any crash occurs user won't see FORCE CLOSE dialog, instead you can show your CUSTOM ERROR message.

It turns out to be better user experience. let me know if you need more info. Good luck :)

Comment: @zack step by step guide is provided on ACRA project page.let me know if any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can to is to avoid getting there. You most probably have a memory leak, but if you really need to work close to the memory limit, the best thing you can do is to catch the OutOfMemoryError you get.

Comment: I'd recommend using the callback function onLowMemory and release some of the memory consuming objects instead of catching OutOfMemoryException.