# Android Force Close Handling Programmatically

Tags: java, android, forceclose

I am working on android app. What i want is to handle Force Close Error that is when ever a force  close occurs I could perform a certain action instead of that force close popup appearance. for e.g a method gets called on a forceclose

```
public void forcecloseoccurs(){
Toast.show("force closed");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455534/android-how-to-handle-force-close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not control force closed pop up directly. Check in your logs what is the error/exception which is causing force close. e.g. if its NullPointerException, you should try handling that.

Comment: There are some tracker available in market to track error & exception.
One of best useful tool is Google Analytics. I used it in my every application. So that time to time we can optimise app based on crash reports.